# Lots of nested match ... case in pattern matching

Tags: scala

I have an automatically generated client for an web service. I has many complicated classes and I have to do a pattern matching against it. For now I have a structure looking like this:

```
val response = client.getResponse
response match {
  case Left(_) => None
  case Right(a: SomeClass) => a match {

    case SomeClass2(b: Option[SomeClass3]) => b match {

      case None => None
      case Some(c: SomeClass3) => c match {

        case SomeClass4(_, _, _, _, d: Seq[SomeClass4]) => d match {
          case Nil => None

          case seq: Seq[SomeClass5] => seq match {
            case Nil => None
            case Seq(xs@_*) => xs map { x =>
              x match {
                case Nil => None

                case SomeClass6(e: SomeClass7) => e match {
                  case Nil => None

                   case SomeClass8(f, _, _, _, _) => f match {
                    case Nil => None
                    case Seq(xs@_*) => xs map { x => 
                      x match {

                        case Nil => None
                        case SomeClass9(g: Seq[SomeClass9], _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => /* + some nested levels more*/
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where `SomeClass1 - SomeClass9` are `case` classes.

As you can see, it seems frightening. What do I do about it? What's the standard way to make it look nicer?

I guess there should be not only refactoring but rather another approach.

Comment: Are you sure `a` is `SomeClass` and `SomeClass2`? Same with `b`, `c` and `d`.

Comment: note that matching on type `A[B]` rather than `A[_]` is generally not possible (and compiler will warn you) since type paramenters are not available at runtime (type erasure). although, you will get an extra "fruitless type test" compiler warning if your over-specific type test is impossible based on the type of the thing you're matching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that `a` should be `SomeClass2`, but not `SomeClass` (same with `b`, `c`, `d`).

You could use alternative patterns like `case A | B => ...` and structural patterns like `Some(MyClass(f))`.

Also you could use partial function in `map` like `map { case ... }` instead of `map { x => x match {...} }`.

And I guess there is a error in your code: there is check for `case Nil => ...; case SomeClass8(...) => ...`.

You could replace `Seq(xs @_*)` with `xs`. If you need entire collection you don't need to extract elements.

Your code:

```
response match {
  case Left(_) | Right(SomeClass2(None)) | Right(SomeClass2(Some(SomeClass3(_, _, _, _, Nil))) => None
  case Right(SomeClass2(Some(SomeClass3(_, _, _, _, xs))) =>
    xs map {
      case SomeClass6(None) | SomeClass6(Some(SomeClass8(Nil, _, _, _, _))) => None
      case SomeClass6(Some(SomeClass8(xs, _, _, _, _))) =>
        xs map {
          case Nil => None
          case SomeClass9(g, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => /* + some nested levels more*/
        }
    }
}
```

You should also extract nested matches to separate methods.

Pattern matching is not the only solution. You could use methods of `Either` and `Option`:

```
response.right.toOption.collect {
  // No need for the first part.
  case SomeClass2(Some(SomeClass3(_, _, _, _, xs)) if xs.nonEmpty => ...
}
```

Comment: **And you don't need to check for Nil and Seq(xs @_*) if xs == Nil. case Seq() => is enough** -- I didn't get it exactly. Can you please explain?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: I've removed this part. You are just checking `d` for `Nil` twice: as `d` and as `seq`.

Answer (score 6):

You might find [extractors](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) useful. It might also be worth flattening some of the cases so you have

```
case Right(SomeClass(SomeClass2(Some(SomeClass3(value))))) => value ...
case _ => None
```

rather than having a `None` case explicitly defined at each level.

Comment: And creating some standard helper functions that hold the inner match statements would obviously reduce the crazy nesting as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably reduce a lot of this complexity by using for comprehensions rather than pattern matching.

One simple opportunity is where you are mapping a sequence to yet another pattern match:

```
case seq: Seq[SomeClass5] => seq match {
  case Nil => None
  case Seq(xs@_*) => xs map { x =>
    x match {
       ...
    }
  }
}
```

This is very ugly because you have used `match` to eliminate the `Nil` case and then matched `seq` *again*.  *Two* levels of `match` to deal with *one* object.  This could become

```
case seq: Seq[SomeClass5] => for (x <- seq) yield {
  x match {
     ...
  }
}
```

This eliminates the `Nil` case check and removes a couple of layers of nesting, which is a big win.   And you do this in at least two layers, so that's an even bigger win.  Of course, this returns a (possibly `Nil`) sequence rather than `f(x)` or `None`, but you can easily convert that.  One way to do this, without adding another of nesting, would be this:

```
case seq: Seq[SomeClass5] => (for (x <- seq) yield {
  x match {
     ...
  }
}) match {
  case Nil => None
  case Seq(i) => Some(i)
  case ...
}
```

Or, if (as I suspect) you expect these sequences only to have one element in them...

```
case seq: Seq[SomeClass5] => (for (x <- seq) yield {
  x match {
     ...
  }
}) match {
  case Seq(i) => Some(i)
  case _ => None
}
```